# Is there an equivalent of the Python range function in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab

Is there an equivalent MATLAB function for the `range()` function in Python?

I'd really like to be able to type something like `range(-10, 11, 5)` and get back `[-10, -5, 0, 5, 10]` instead of having to write out the entire range by hand.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, there is the `:` operator. The command `-10:5:11` would produce the vector `[-10, -5, 0, 5, 10];`

Answer (score 8):

There are two relevant functions.  The colon `:` operator, you can use the `linspace` function.  The best function to use depends on what you want to specify.

Examples:

```
x = -10:5:10;              % Count by 5's from -10 to 10.  (or "colon(-10, 5, 10)")
x = linspace(-10, 10, 5);  % 5 even increments between -10 and 10
```

The result of the `colon` operator will always include the first argument and the desired spacing, but generally will not include the last argument.  (e.g. `x = -10:5:11`).

The `linspace` function will always include the desired first and last elements, but will the element spacing will vary.  (e.g. `linspace(-10, 11, 5)`).

Answer (score 3):

Others have mentioned the [`colon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html) operator. You just have to be aware of some differences.

In Python, [`range`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) takes all integer parameters and returns an integer list. In MATLAB, the colon operator can handle floating point in both the start/stop as well as the step size.

I would say that [`numpy.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) is a closer match to MATLAB's colon operator.